# Google Places API - find an address using the city

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I am planning to use Google Places API in order to create an address autocomplete in my web site. My question is about whether my requirements are possible using Google Places.

I have a "Post Request" page where the user posts an address (city, street and house number). I also have a "Search" page where the user can search posts according to the city. Here the user only inserts a city name, without a street and house number.

My questions:

1. Can I force the user to insert a city, street and house number (inserts of only city or only city and street for example will alert invalid input, or the autocomplete will return only results of city, street and house number)?
2. Can I force the user insert city only (without street and house number)?
3. Assuming the user posts an address with "MyCity, MyStreet 12". In the background of the application I get an id of this specific location and store it. Another user is searching for posts and inserts "MyCity". In the background I get the specific id of "MyCity" and use this id in order to search in my db. How can I find the result of the first user: "MyCity, MyStreet 12" using "MyCity" key?
   In other words, assume I have a location id that represents a city and other location id that represents fully address (city, street, house number), how can I check if the fully address belong to the city using the ids only?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as what the user types into the input box that is associated with the `Autocomplete`[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#places_autocomplete), there isn't very much you can do to control what they type. However, when you set up the `Autocomplete`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete), you can define options that control the results that will come back. The key for you will be setting up the `types` option correctly.

Specific to your question **#1**, you can restrict the results that will come back in the `Autocomplete` to addresses by setting `types` to `geocode` as shown in this example:

```
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
  new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));

var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  bounds: defaultBounds,
  types: ['geocode']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Specific to your question **#2**, you can restrict the results that come back in the `Autocomplete` to cities by setting `types` to `cities` as shown here:

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
  types: ['(cities)'],
  componentRestrictions: {country: 'fr'}
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Also notice that because the `Autocomplete` has been restricted to `(cities)`, I have added a `componentRestrictions` specifier to set the country within which to search for cities (in this case, France) and removed the `bounds` specifier.

Specific to your question **#3**, you can create two tables, one to store **City** data, the other to store **Address** data, as shown in the following UML diagram:

[image]

Based on the description in your question, there are some key aspects of this design:

- There is a one-to-many relationship from `City` to `Address`. This will allow you to associate many `Address` records to a single `City` record. It will also make it simple to retrieve all of the `Address` records that have been entered for any `City`.
- The relationship between `Address` and `City` says that for *every* `Address`, a `City` must exist. This means that when a user enters an `Address`, you must take the following actions: 1 - Check to see if the `City` for the `Address` already exists in the database. 2 - If the `City` *does* exist, retrieve its `ID` and use that as the foreign key `City-ID` value when storing the new `Address`. 3 - If the `City` *does not* exist, a new unique `ID` must be created for the `City` and the `City` must be stored in the database. Then the `ID` for the `City` may be used as the foreign key `City-ID` value when storing the `Address`. Making sure that every `Address` has an associated `City` answers one of the questions you ask as part of your question #3: **How can I find the result of the first user: "MyCity, MyStreet 12" using "MyCity" key?** Because when you stored the "MyCity, MyStreet 12" `Adress` record, you made sure a "MyCity" record exists in the `City` table. Retrieving the `ID` for the `City` is straightforward if another user enters the same `City` or an `Address` associated with the same `City` is entered by a user in the future.
- The relationship between `City` and `Address` says that for any `City` there may be zero or more associated `Address` records. This ensures that the user in your description that searches for just a `City` may store the `City` even if no follow-up `Address` searches take place. The `City` is stored, it has an `ID`, and it is just waiting for any new `Address` records that may be added later.

Finally, you asked one more question as part of question #3: **how can I check if the fully address belong to the city using the ids only?** Being able to answer this question is why there is a foreign key `City-ID` that is part of every `Address` record. It clearly defines the `City` that is associated with any `Address`. So if you have the `ID` for a `City` and the `ID` for an `Address`, the simplest way to determine if they are a match is: 1 - Retrieve the `Address` from the database using the `Address` `ID`. 2 - Compare the `City-ID` value that is part of the `Address` that was just retrieved from the database with the `ID` for the `City` you started with; if they match, you know the `Address` is associated with the `City` and if they don't match, you can be sure there is no relationship between that `Address` and that `City`.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with the addresses and the cities, but I've tried to give you a solid solution that covers the things you describe in your question. I included a great deal of detail so that all of your points are addressed and in the hope that it will make my description clear and easy to understand. I hope this helps you -

Comment: Yes, the added clarification helps a great deal. I have added more content to my original answer based on your added clarification.

Comment: Your answear is great except that I hoped to get streets list from google so that I could use Autocomplete for the streets. Thanks for the creativity. :)

Comment: This answer is great for me.. But as much as i understand it doesn't stands with google api terms. According to the api we cannot store data.Please correct me if i am wrong.. And i am hoping i am wrong :)

Comment: @Aviad Well, it depends. There are Google geographic data sources; some accessed from a JavaScript library, others that are direct service API calls. The terms of service vary; some explicitly forbid use for gathering and storing persistent data, while others encourage that usage model. I believe that what you are asking is actually a separate question and not a follow-up to this question, so I encourage you to open a new question, describe what you would like to achieve in detail, and you will receive guidance about specific service terms and the options that Google has available.

Comment: @SeanMickey Thanks for the response. Actually i believe the answer can really be helpful because that what i need.. Anyway i have opened a question about this issue.. But no one answered :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33068935/google-places-api-airbnb
Maybe you can take a look on this one

Answer (score 0):

This is more a Javascript question than Google Places.

Use a Javascript routine to validate the form, and, say in case #1, checks that all fields are filled out. On the other hand, for case #2, you could disable/remove the fields you don't want filled out, and post the request with only what you want to send.

For #3, it's just a question of caching. Use localStorage, or an array, to store the city as key, and the result as value.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand my question.

Comment: Then I believe you'd better rephrase.

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot see what I can improve. Sean Mickey understood me, maby you should ask him.

Comment: "say in case #1, checks that all fields are filled out" => I have only one field contains the fully address. "for case #2, you could disable/remove the fields you don't want filled out" => Same. "For #3, it's just a question of caching. Use localStorage.." => local storage between for server side redirects?

Answer (score 0):

Google Places will help your user autocomplete their address as Sean Mickey describes:

1. They start typing their *street address* in a single field
2. Google gives them a list of possible matching addresses
3. They pick one, and you get back a response [like this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/autocomplete#place_autocomplete_responses)

The `id` in that response is going to be for their street address, not for the city.  So it's not going to be useful the way you want.  If you want to match on city, you need to store the *name* of the city (if you want you can create your own id table).

Think about how you want to implement location search in your database:

- Search by city (misses people who live just outside the city limits)
- Search by distance (finds everyone within a certain radius)

If you choose to search by distance, you should also be storing the Latitude and Longitude that Google Places gives you back when the user enters their address.  You also need to read up on how to do [spatial search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch) in your database (especially geodist).