# How to get the nearest city from google place api (android) based on a given latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am getting a latitude and longitude from GPS and want to search the nearest city from my current location.

Currently I'm sending a request to Google Places with types like "neighborhood|locality", but this does not return any nearest city. Even if I only specify "neighborhood" or "locality" by themselves, I still get no results. However if I use a type like "bar" then it returns a list of bars.

I'm using the types listed here:

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/supported_types

Can anybody tell me what Place Type I should use to get the nearest city or places, or how I can otherwise get the nearest city?

Comment: Hey could you post a partial URL or example of what exactly your request looks like?

Comment: What do you mean "it returns 'bars'"? Are you saying that's literally the text your get back? Is it giving you a list of bars? What happens if you only pass one of "neighborhood" or "locality"? Does it work then?

Comment: You might want to use something called `GeoCoder`.

Comment: Hello, culix ya it returns list of bars :) and if i pass neighborhood or locality than nothing will return

Comment: @Amit Ahh, so you're not actually trying to return a list of neighborhoods inside a city, but you're trying to get the city name? I have edited the last sentence of your question to (hopefully) make that more clear. See what you think of my answer below.

Comment: Hello culix, but i just want to get nearest list of cities based on my current location! can you post what is the types i have to pass! I do not know what is the actual type i have to pass i think it should be "neighborhoods" or "locality" so i am passing that

Comment: @Amit Hey I see you accepted my answer. Thanks! Does that mean it worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting back a results array with nothing in it, or simply getting nothing back? [The docs say](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceSearchResults) you'll get a results array "even if the service returns no results". Is it possible that the city you're searching contains bars but does not contain anything classified as a "neighborhood" or a "locality"?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699553/28037) says

> you can restrict the results that will come back in the Autocomplete
>   to addresses by setting types to 'geocode' ... you can restrict the
>   results that come back in the Autocomplete to cities by setting types
>   to 'cities'

If you're just trying to get the city name, rather than searching for something inside the city, perhaps you want to use one of those options?