# Google places api - airbnb

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I would like to use the api like airbnb. I have search and read all posts/stackoveflow/google group that i can. I couldn't find the answer

In general i would like to do the following:

1. Would like the user to have the ability to insert advertise with full address
2. I would like to search in my db by city/street/country and radius according to users ads
3. Does i have to use api key? I have found autocomplete example without the api key and i works fine

Hope it makes sense.. I have looked on this [Google group thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-places-api/um-uek3Zvyg/2eGfrKI1_CkJ) and this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10463286/google-places-api-find-an-address-using-the-city/10699553#10699553).. But i am not sure if this flow is allowed and optimise.

Thanks